# How to get callBack from react.createref()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I use `react.createref()` for call the function in another file like this

```
//Login.js
handleAcceptClose() {
    let mmp = this.childRef.current.checkWhatIs();
    if (mmp === 1){
        this.setState({ open: false })
    }
}
```

and this is a `checkWhatIs` function

```
//register.js
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    checkWhatIs,
}));
const checkWhatIs = async (status, id) => {
    const temp5 = await register()
    createNotification(temp5)
    return temp5
}
```

the problem is when the function `checkWhatIs` called and get the job done nothing returned in `handleAcceptClose` in `Login.js`

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question, but `if (mmp === 1){` will always be false, because checkWhatIs returns a promise, not a number.